# Django taggit, listing count for each tag

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Let's say I have three tags. I want to show how many objects are linked to it. Like so:

Apple (3)
Orange (0)
Banana (5)

How do I make it work the simplest way possible, preferably without creating new attributes in the database?

I'm guessing I'll need to iterate through all the tags, count them, and put both together inside a dictionary, right? Eg:

```
something = {'apple': X, 'orange': X, etc...
```

Then make that available in the context, so that it's accessible in the HTML template? Or is there a simpler way? Thank you!

Comment: If you add your models for objects and tags code then there might be a better way. Other than that what you are doing is fine too.

Answer (score 4):

I did this with an annotated queryset.

```
queryset = Tag.objects.all()
queryset2 = queryset.annotate(num_times=Count('taggit_taggeditem_items'))
```

You can then make a dictionary if you want to:

```
mydict = {}
for tag in querset2:
    mydict[tag.name] = tag.num_times
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [django-taggit-templatetags2](https://github.com/fizista/django-taggit-templatetags2)

Then add in your `template`:

```
{% load taggit_templatetags2_tags %}

{% get_taglist as tags for 'yourapp.yourmodel' %}
  ...

  <ul>
    {% for tag in tags %}
      <li>{{tag}} ({{tag.num_times}})</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>

  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the easiest way to do that is by querying the tagged model using `aggregate`, summing up the tags.